# c++/clr StructureToPtr exit application without any exception or error

Tags: c++, clr

I have a piece of code that transform a managed object into unmanaged object as per below,

```
 static void M2N(M managed, N* pNative){
        Marshal::StructureToPtr(managed, IntPtr(pNative), true);
    };
```

my problem is after calling the above piece of code on certain `struct`, the code exits mysteriously without any exception, the tranformation is obviously unsuccessful (I have tried with some other struct, it works).

My question is how can I at least produce some exception, so that I know where went wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the Try Catch keyWord?

Comment: Corrupting the stack frame would be a good way to trigger this failfast exit.  Look in the Output window for the process exit code.

Comment: @HansPassant i have written a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040244/c-clr-structuretoptr-stack-buffer-overflow, hope you can take a look

Comment: Right, stack buffer overrun as I guessed.  Don't stop until sizeof(N) in native code is equal to Marshal.SizeOf(M) in managed code.  Divide and conquer, start with half of the fields commented out and work your way up or down to find the evildoer.

Comment: Hi, thanks. but what do you mean by sizeof(N) in native code is equal to Marshal.SizeOf(M) in managed code, could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @HansPassant another question is do we know the evildoer is the managed part or unmanaged part?

Comment: It doesn't matter, somebody is wrong.  Usually not the native code programmer because he isn't picking up the phone and it is your code that is corrupting his stack.